# Can a wizard cast Shield using a higher level spell slot?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Let's say I'm a Level 7 Wizard and I have no spell slots of 1st level left, but I do have some of 3rd and 4th level.

Can I cast *Shield* as a reaction after getting hit by an attack by using a 4th level spell slot?

Preparing and Casting Spells:

> The Wizard table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your
>   spells of 1st level and higher. To cast one of these spells, you must
>   expend a slot of the spell's level or **higher**. You regain all
>   expended slots when you finish a long rest. (PHB p. 114)

By RAW I think is this possible: am I correct?

Comment: Warlocks would be in very deep trouble otherwise

Answer (score 41):

Yes.  You can cast any spell using a slot of the same level as the spell, or higher.

From PHB page 201, Chapter 10: Spellcasting:

> **SPELL SLOTS**
>
> [...]
>   When a character casts a spell, he or she expends
>   a slot of that spell's level or higher, effectively "filling"
>   a slot with the spell. [...]

and, later on the same page:

> **CASTING A SPELL AT A HIGHER LEVEL**
>
> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a
>   higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher
>   level for that casting. For instance, if Umara casts magic
>   missile using one of her 2nd-level slots, that magic
>   missile is 2nd level. Effectively, the spell expands to fill
>   the slot it is put into.
>
> Some spells, such as magic missile and cure wounds, have more powerful effects when cast at a higher level, as detailed in a spell's description.

Note: In your example, you had both 3rd and 4th level spells slots remaining.  You can cast *Shield* with either a 3rd or 4th level slot but (as there is no enhanced effect for that spell when cast at higher levels - a *Shield* spell is a *Shield* spell no matter what level it's cast at), it would be best to cast it as third level spell - keeping the 4th level slot for  future 4th-or-lower level spells.  *Shield* doesn't benefit from higher slot levels, but some other level 1-3 spells you might want to cast do.

In other words, **cast it with the lowest level slot that will achieve the desired effect**, taking into account any possible enhancements from casting at higher slot levels

For example, as mentioned by Mark Cogan, when casting *Dispel Magic* or *Counterspell* at higher levels, each increase in slot level increases the level of spell which can be automatically dispelled/interrupted without a spellcasting ability roll.

Similarly, *Fireball* can be cast using any slot of level 3 or higher - but you don't need to use a 9th level slot against a bunch of kobolds unless you have no lower-level slots remaining.

Answer (score 22):

You are correct: any memorized spell can be cast with any slot of equal or greater level.

Usually this is done for a spell such as Magic Missile, for increased effectiveness. Shield gains no such benefit. However, the level at which you cast Shield is pertinent for its interactions with Dispel Magic: *since a spell assumes the higher level for that casting, it is harder to dispel*. I point this out since one of the key uses for Shield at higher levels is that it nullifies castings of Magic Missile. In a wizard duel, dispel magic is often tossed about.

Citation:

[Casting a Spell at Higher Level, page 100](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/SRD-OGL_V1.1.pdf)

Comment: Casting at a higher level also makes a spell harder to counterspell, which in the case of shield seems far more valuable.

Comment: @Miniman: Though in many cases, trading a first level slot for a wasted Shield to force your opponent to blow a third level slot for Counterspell is a good tradeoff. Depends how nasty the attack you're Shield-ing against is of course (first level Shield saving you from a swarm of Tiny animated objects doing 10d4 + 40 damage might be worth upcasting).